# Setting Navigation Value Based On What The Function Returns

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

When I call a login function, this is the error I get:

```
Error: You need to specify name or key when calling navigate with an object as the argument. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions#navigate for usage.
```

This is my code:

`login.jsx`

```
<TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate(this.onClick())}>
                <Icon
                  style={styles.buttonIcon}
                  name="arrow-right"
                  size={30}
                  color="white"
                  type="feather"
                />
```

This is the function:

`ParticleAuth.js`

```
onClick = async () => {
  this.init();
  this.setLanguage();
  this.setChainInfo();
  this.login();
  const result = await particleAuth.isLogin();
  console.log('Result:', result);
  if (result) {
    return "LoggedIn"; // LoggedIn & Error are names of screens
  } else {
    return "Error";
  }
};
```

According to the error, I have to preset the value for `navigation.navigate`. What might be some alternate code to mine?

Thanks!

Comment: Your onClick function is async. You need to await the result of the onClick (currently you are returning a promise instead of a string). I would suggest you to call `navigation.navigate` inside the onClick function.

Comment: I still end up getting the same error.

Comment: I found the solution. It's not the most efficient, but I used an intermediary screen called `Loading` while the login function works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your `navigation` to `onClick()` function and navigate to the screen in there as below:

```
<TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={this.onClick}>
                <Icon
                  style={styles.buttonIcon}
                  name="arrow-right"
                  size={30}
                  color="white"
                  type="feather"
                />
```

```
onClick = async () => {
  this.init();
  this.setLanguage();
  this.setChainInfo();
  this.login();
  const result = await particleAuth.isLogin();
  console.log('Result:', result);

  // change this lines
  let screenName = '';
  if (result) {
    screenName = "LoggedIn"; // LoggedIn & Error are names of screens
  } else {
    screenName = "Error";
  }
  navigation.navigate(screenName);
};
```

Comment: Yup! This works too, but I realised having a loading screen was better for the overall appearance as well.

Answer (score 0):

***I found the solution. It's not the most efficient, but I used an intermediary screen called Loading while the login function works***